# Why I get $Proxy0 cannot be cast to when class inherits from Thread or implements interface?

Tags: java, netbeans, aop

I tried to implement AOP but I get exception `(java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to myPackage.Person` on (2) line. What could be the problem? The `Person` must be Thread, so it extends `Thread` class.

**MAIN**

```
1. ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/appContext.xml");
2. Person p = (Person)ctx.getBean("p1");
3. p.start();
```

**PERSON**

```
public class Person extends Thread{

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        setPersonName(name);
    }

    public void setPersonName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

**ASPECT**

```
public class LogSettersCalls {

    public void logSetterCall(JoinPoint theJoinPoint)
    {
        String methodName = theJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object newValue = theJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        Object theObject = theJoinPoint.getTarget();
        System.out.println(theObject );
    }
}
```

**CONFIG**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(void set*(*))" id="theSettersLogger" />
        <aop:aspect ref="logSettersCallsBean">
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="theSettersLogger" method="logSetterCall"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
   <bean id="logSettersCallsBean" class="aop.LogSettersCalls" />


    <bean id="p1" class="myPackage.Person" >    
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="igor"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

df

Comment: I suspect your proxy can only implement interfaces, not concrete classes. In any case, it bad practice to extend a Thread.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add the tag "spring" to your question, too, e.g. to differentiate your question from the ones concerning AspectJ. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that I'm not sure it's intuitive or suitable to derive `Person` from `Thread` (can you not use composition or similar?), I suspect the issue is that the AOP is rewriting your class and it's no longer a `Person`.

I would separate the implementation (`PersonImpl`) from a suitable interface (`Person`) and the cast should then work.

Comment: do you mean to do something like this `PersonIml extends Person`?

Comment: Or rather PersonImpl implements Person, since Person is an interface. But, yes

Comment: But I need the `Person` to be `Thread`, how I can achieve it?